# Cannot access any time (created_at, updated_at) variables in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, model

All my models have the fields `created_at` and `updated_at` (like default), they have not been modified or changed in any way.  If I were to go into the rails console and type something like:

```
user = User.first
user.created_at > 5.years.ago
```

it returns `true` as it should.  However, if I attempt to do the exact same thing in a controller, I get the error saying `>` cannot be called on a nil object.  To further this, in any view, if I were to use a previously defined variable `@user` and type:

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

it prints the name without issue. However, if I were to type:

```
<%= @user.created_at %>
```

I get nothing (meaning it is nil).  This is the case for every model and every controller view - I've tested it thoroughly and can't get it to work, and I've googled extensively - any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT: Controller code:

```
def active
  @user = current_user
  @items = @user.items.where(active: true).order('created_at DESC')
  @alerts = false
  if @user.items.where.not(deal_price: nil).where(active: true) != []
    @alerts = true
  end
  cookies[:item_temp_url] = ""

  if @user.created_at > 5.seconds.ago
    @display_welcome = true
  end
end
```

And the error:

```
undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code where you're seeing this issue?

Comment: Just posted it, thanks

Comment: It seems as though the `current_user` method is returning `nil`. Can you share that code as well?

Comment: it is not - if I do @user.name in the view or anywhere it isn't nil... I've used that code for months without issue.  This is the first time im messing with the datetime it is something unique to those types of fields only

Comment: Dump your current schema and make sure that your users table has a created_at column.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out something got corrupted with the database (values weren't transferring to the Rails front-end.  I restarted all Ruby processes and dropped and recreated the database, and the error disappeared.